# how to add automatic id in excel

Tags: excel, numbers, auto-generate, generate

I need Some Help
Can you tell me how to solve this problem in excel

my problem:

```
i have 3 columns like no. name and amount
```

i just need
when i add name in column
automatic add id number in "no. columns"

for example
if i put name in C10 then automatic add id number in B10
and then i put again name in c13 and i want to add id number in b13

please look this image:
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DRAU.png)

please tell me

which formula is used for number id

```
               b             c             d
              no.         name          amount
         10    1         google         
         11               
         12    3         Facebook
         13    2         youtube
```

i just put name with ordering like 1=google and 2=youtube ......

And sorry for bad English because I don't know English well

Comment: I assume you have a reference list so use `index/match`.

Comment: You may try anyone of these, • `=IF(B2="","",MAX($A$1:A1)+1)`, • `=IF(B2="","",COUNTA($B$2:B2))` , • `=IF(B2="","",SUBTOTAL(3,$B$2:B2))`

Answer (score 0):

in B Column, Use the Below Function in B2, First Keep B1=1

=IF(LEN(C2)=0,"",B1+1)

I think This Helps to your Requirement